htaccess Force All Users to https
I have a valid SSL certificate for my website and want to redirect all traffic to https. I have already modified htaccess previously to enable more legible URLs (things like www.site.com/words/that/mean/something redirects to www.site.com/script.php?id=123) and that works just great
Now I want to additionally redirect all requests to https. A quick Google search led me to add the following code to the beginning of my htaccess, before my existing rewrite rules and some 301 redirects from old pages that no longer exist:
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule    ^about/?$    about.php    [NC,L]    # Process events
RewriteRule    ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    detail-view.php?event_url=$1    [NC,L]    # Process events

redirect 301 /Galleries.html http://www.site.com/gallery.php
redirect 301 /about.html http://www.site.com/about.php


But when I then try to visit www.site.com, I get a too many redirects error and the page doesn't load.
Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong? Maybe I need to put the https as part of the existing RewriteRules, and then add the default case at the very end to catch everything else? That way, there is only 1 redirect?
